# POSTing ViewModel contained in other ViewModel asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a ViewModel which contains two other ViewModels (stripped for brevity):

```
class SmallViewModel1
{
    public string Item { get; set; }
}

class SmallViewModel2
{
    public string Item { get; set;}
}

class BigViewModel {
    public SmallViewModel1 Model1 { get; set; }
    public SmallViewModel2 Model2 { get; set; }
}
```

I then have a View which accepts `BigViewModel` as its model. The view has two forms which POST to two different actions.

```
@model BigViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Action1","Controller",FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(t=>t.Model1.Item)
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Action2","Controller",FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(t=>t.Model2.Item)
}
```

Then in the controller I am trying to do something like this:

```
public ActionResult Action1(SmallViewModel1 model)
{
    ....
}

public ActionResult Action2(SmallViewModel2 model)
{
    ....
}
```

The issue I am running into is if I use the 'For' controls (EditorFor, TextBoxFor, etc) my POSTed model is null. I think this is because it expects me to POST the full ViewModel (BigViewModel) and it names the inputs expecting this: `<input name="Model1.Item"`. To get around this I have been using the non 'For' control and just setting the name to the SmallViewModel's property, for example: `@Html.TextBox("Item")`. This maps correctly to the controller and everything ends up working.

My questions is am I doing this correctly? I've been googling around for a bit and haven't found anything but I feel like there is a better, or more 'best-practice' way to do this.

Comment: You can not do like this.You have to create `partial view` and pass the `small view model` to them

Comment: Thats because your generating controls based on `BigViewModel`, so you either need to change the parameters in the POST methods to match - i.e. `public ActionResult Action1(BigViewModelmodel)` or use the `[Bind(Prefix="SmallViewModel1 ")]` attribute

Comment: **Do not** create partials - it will be generating invalid html if there are duplicate property names.

Comment: @CodeNotFound Turn that into an answer so I can accept it please :). I knew I was missing something obvious.Thanks!

Comment: @James the correct answer if you don't want to use BugViewModel is to use the Stephen's solution :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Good call on the duplicate property names. [Bind(Prefix)] was the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Controller should be like this

```
public ActionResult Action1(BigViewModel model)
{
    ....
}

public ActionResult Action2(BigViewModel model)
{
    ....
}
```

As you have taken BigViewModel, When you submit it should have same model in parameter

Alternatively you can use the `Prefix` property of the `BindAttribute`

```
public ActionResult Action1([Bind(Prefix="Model1")]SmallViewModel1 model)
{
    ....
}

public ActionResult Action2([Bind(Prefix="Model2")]SmallViewModel2 model)
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: the Op => " think this is because it expects me to POST the full ViewModel (BigViewModel)"

Comment: I think, this is the best practice and correct way to implement code successfully.!

Comment: Hum I think @Stephen Muecke gives the correct answer in the comments of the question.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke- You teach me something new. I never know about [Bind(Prefix)]. That's why I love <3 to do Stackoverflow. You always learn something new.